Unable to register rewrite rule using add_rewrite_rule
I am trying to add a rewrite rule to my plugin but somehow I can not get it to work in any way I find online. Right now I simplified it (to start debugging and moving it to the correct place later) by trying to add the action in the main plugin file and also flushing the rewrite rules there, this is ofcourse what I have in mind for the final solution but even this does not work.
<?php
/* 

Plugin Name: Binding Event Register 

Plugin URI: https://www.sanderhansen.nl/

Description: Plugin created for Stichting de Binding to create forms to register for their activities 

Version: 1.0.0

Author: Sander Wilbert Hansen 

Author URI: https://www.sanderhansen.nl/ 

License: GPLv2 or later 

Text Domain: bindingregister 

*/

// If this file is called directly, abort.
if (!defined('WPINC')) {
  die;
}

/**
 * Currently plugin version.
 */
define('BINDING_REGISTER_VERSION', '1.0.0');

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin activation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-plugin-name-activator.php
 * 
 * @since    1.0.0 
 */
function br_activate()
{
  require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/br-activator.php';
  br_Activator::activate();
}

/**
 * The code that runs during plugin deactivation.
 * This action is documented in includes/class-plugin-name-deactivator.php
 * 
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function br_deactivate()
{
  require_once plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/br-deactivator.php';
  br_Deactivator::deactivate();
}

register_activation_hook(__FILE__, 'br_activate');
register_deactivation_hook(__FILE__, 'br_deactivate');

/**
 * The core plugin class that is used to define internationalization,
 * admin-specific hooks, and public-facing site hooks.
 */
require plugin_dir_path(__FILE__) . 'includes/binding-register.php';

/**
 * Begins execution of the plugin.
 *
 * Since everything within the plugin is registered via hooks,
 * then kicking off the plugin from this point in the file does
 * not affect the page life cycle.
 *
 * @since    1.0.0
 */
function br_run()
{

  $binding_register = new Binding_Register();
  $binding_register->run();
}

/* Log to File
 * Description: Log into system php error log, usefull for Ajax and stuff that FirePHP doesn't catch
 */
function debug_log($msg, $name = '')
{
  // Print the name of the calling function if $name is left empty
  $trace = debug_backtrace();
  $name = ('' == $name) ? $trace[1]['function'] : $name;

  $error_dir = '/var/www/html/php_error.log';
  $msg = print_r($msg, true);
  $log = $name . "  |  " . $msg . "\n";
  error_log($log, 3, $error_dir);
}

function test_rewrite_rule() {
  add_rewrite_rule('^testendpoint/?$', 'index.php?testvar=1', 'top');
  flush_rewrite_rules(); // Temporarily here for testing, but should be moved to activation hook.
}
add_action('init', 'test_rewrite_rule');

function custom_query_vars_filter($vars) {
  $vars[] = 'testvar';
  return $vars;
}
add_filter('query_vars', 'custom_query_vars_filter');

add_action('template_redirect', function() {
  if (get_query_var('testvar') !== '') {
      echo 'Test endpoint hit!';
      exit;
  }
});

add_action('wp_footer', function() {
  global $wp_rewrite;
  debug_log($wp_rewrite->rules);
}, 9999);

// run the actual plugin
br_run();

$wp_rewrite->rules is empty and does not print anything, also using the Rewrite Rules Inspector plugin I do not see anything. The direct call using the query var however does work.
Does anyone know what I am doing wrong?
